# Entity Framework: Using Multiple Junction Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I've designed a database, paying a lot of attention to normalization.
Here's a piece of it:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vbiw.png]

First of all, If you notice any issues with this design, feel free to let me know.

The goal is to have companies, each of which have some departments.
Departments can be shared between companies.
As in:
`Company 1` can have `Department 1, 2 and 3.`
`Company 2` can have `Department 1, 5, 8 and 9.`

The `BusinessUnits` will have access to `departments`.
But it depends on the company to which a `department` is linked.

`BusinessUnit 1` may have permission to access `Department 1` of `Company 1`, but should not be able to access `Department 1` of `Company 2`.

The `CompanyDepartment` config table is pretty obvious.
It links a Company to (possibly) multiple departments.

The `CompanyDepartmentBusinessUnit` config table is used to link `BusinessUnits` to `Departments` of a `Company`.
In this table, the `CompanyId` and `DepartmentId` form a composite Foreign Key to the primary key of `CompanyDepartment` (which is: `CompanyId` and `DepartmentId` as well).

I'm using a Database-First approach in Entity Framework.
For the simple junction tables, I've overwritten the `OnModelCreating` method in my `DbContext`.

An example of how I did this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V8Uf.png]

My question now is: how do I do this for the `CompanyDepartmentBusinessUnit` relation?

Say that my user chose to see the departments of `Company 1`.
I want to filter all the `Departments` that are linked to `Company 1` but are also visible to the `BusinessUnit` in which the user resides (for instance `Business Unit 2`).

Thank you in advance and enjoy your holidays!

Comment: I'm confused. You say *Database First* which in EF terms means `edmx`, but then overriding `OnModelCreating`, which is *Code First* feature. So what actually is it? Besides that, you can't use many-to-many with implicit junction table in this scenario, you have to use explicit link entity.

Comment: @IvanStoev DatabaseFirst does not imply an edmx file. It could also mean that the entity model is regenerated after the database changes, which in theory could be done by somebody outside the development team.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I know the terms are confusing and badly chosen, but still non `edmx` models are called *Code First* model regardless of whether they are generated from database or vise versa.

Comment: @IvanStoev right, thanks for clarifying :). I was confused indeed.

Comment: Argh, getting bad memory flashbacks now. This is why I've switched over to micro-ORMS like PetaPoco...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF allows you to use implicit junction table only if (1) it has no additional columns and (2) if it's not referenced by other entity different than the two ends of the many-to-many relationships.

`CompanyDepartment` satisfies the condition (1), but not (2) because it's referenced from `CompanyDepartmentBusinessUnit`, hence you need to use explcit entity with two one-to-many relationships.

Once you do that, it can be seen that now `CompanyDepartmentBusinessUnit` satisfies both conditions, hence can be modelled with implicit junction table for `BusinessUnit` and `CompanyDepartment`.

With that being said, the final model would be something like this:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CompanyDepartment> DepartmentLinks { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CompanyDepartment> CompanyLinks { get; set; }
}

public class BusinessUnit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsPersonal { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CompanyDepartment> CompanyDepartments { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyDepartment
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BusinessUnit> BusinessUnits { get; set; }
}
```

and taking into account the default EF conventions, with the following minimal fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().ToTable("Company");
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().ToTable("Department");
modelBuilder.Entity<BusinessUnit>().ToTable("BusinessUnit");
modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyDepartment>().ToTable("CompanyDepartment");

modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyDepartment>()                
    .HasKey(e => new { e.CompanyId, e.DepartmentId });

modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyDepartment>()
    .HasMany(e => e.BusinessUnits)
    .WithMany(e => e.CompanyDepartments)
    .Map(m => m
        .MapLeftKey("CompanyId", "DepartmentId")
        .MapRightKey("BusinessUnitId")
        .ToTable("CompanyDepartmentBusinessUnit")
    );
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan! This is indeed what I was looking for, it does the job. Sorry to confuse some people in my question. I am fairly new to using EF. I have some experience in designing databases, so I've designed one before starting on the application. Maybe I chose the wrong wording, but I am using my database as reference. I did not generate any entities or context, I am doing all of that myself. Maybe that's really bad, and I should let EF do some work for me, but I don't really like generated code  If you have some advice on that part, feel free to guide me, but a big thank you anyway!

Comment: What are you doing is perfectly valid and supported approach (I don't like generated code either :)) Confusing is the name of the methodology chosen by MS, and in particular the word "First". The essential part is the word "Code", i.e. code model vs edmx (xml) model. What about what is first and what second, use whatever is more comfortable for you. There is absolutely no problem doing it either way as soon as you can properly map the two. Cheers.